# Magento 2 custom notifications

Tags: magento2, module, admin, event-observer, adminnotification

am trying to insert custom notifications into adminnotification_inbox table as per core module Magento-AdminNotifications approache but am't able to insert custom notifications.
Code is in below

**events.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="controller_action_predispatch">
    <observer name="adminnotification" instance="MyNameSpace\MyModuleName\Observer\PredispatchAdminActionControllerObserver" />
</event>
```

NameSpace/ModuleName/Model/Feed.php

```
<?php namespace  ConversionBug\Core\Model;
```

Class Feed extends \Magento\AdminNotification\Model\Feed{

```
  public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger, 
                              \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date) {
    $this->_logger = $logger;        
    $this->date = $date;

}
  public function checkUpdate() {
    $this->_logger->debug("Feed Message here");
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info('Your text message');
    $this->logger->debug($message);
  }
```

}

Comment: Your code only shows attempts to log message. What did you try to insert notifications ?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to inject `Magento/AdminNotification/Model/InboxFactory` in your constructor:

```
protected $_inboxFactory;

public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger, 
                              \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date,
                              \Magento\AdminNotification\Model\InboxFactory $inboxFactory) {
    $this->_logger = $logger;        
    $this->date = $date;
    $this->_inboxFactory = $inboxFactory;
}
```

Then you will need to have data stored in an array like this:

```
$data = [
    'severity' => $severity,
    'date_added' => $itemPublicationDate,
    'title' => $title,
    'description' => $description,
    'url' => $link
];
```

Finally you can insert your admin notification in the database by calling:

```
$this->_inboxFactory->create()->parse($data);
```